# Spring Boot, Html button which will add parameters to table in database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to make a link or another html element which will add parameters to table in MySQL database using JPA and Thymeleaf. I've made a link which have a good url (create a new parameters in table) but after click on this element firefox says : "The address wasn’t understood" but manually entered the same url works. I need that element in index.html which after click will insert into table values. Thank you.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return "index";
}

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@RequestMapping("/create")
@ResponseBody
public String create(String email, String name) {
    String userId="";
    try {
        User user = new User(email, name);
        userDao.save(user);
        userId = String.valueOf(user.getId());
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        return "Error creating the user" + exception.toString();
    }
    return "User succesfully created with id = " + userId;
}
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HomePage</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<a href="localhost:8080/create/email=john10234@gmail.com&name=John">Click to 
add: ([id], 'john10234@gmail.com', 'John')
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed ? in url
your url will
`a href="localhost:8080/create?email=john10234@gmail.com&name=John">`
instead of a `href="localhost:8080/create/email=john10234@gmail.com&name=John">`

Also use @RequestParam

`@RequestMapping("/create")
@ResponseBody
public String create(@RequestParam("email")String email, @RequestParam("name")String name)`

Comment: Url was written fine (with '?' insted of '/') As you recomended I added a @RequestParam but it did not change anything.

Comment: can you try with prefix http:// with url, http://localhost:8080/create/email=john10234@gmail.com&name=John

Comment: href="http://localhost:8080/create/email=john10234@gmail.com&name=John "

Comment: Reason: Firefox doesn’t know how to open this address(without prefix http /https), default it use protocols (osu)  and it's not aware of you localhost protocol that why you were getting "The address wasn’t understood", so use prefix http

Comment: @kacmak7 cool , please accept the so it can help another person